# Как прочесть с помощью php большой json файл?

Tags: php, json

Есть json файл популярных авиамаршрутов (по всему миру), весит чуть больше 13 мегабайт, я понимаю что там этих маршрутов нереально много. На элементе с индексом 64 963 у меня падает локальный сервер. На хостинге скрипт вообще отказывается выполнять json_decode().

Я пытаюсь этот файл прочесть и засунуть в mysql базу данных, но из-за падения сервера, ничего не выходит. Может есть возможность как-то разбить его чтение на этапы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ищите потоковые парсеры JSON. Они разбирают JSON по принципу SAX, то есть не читая всё целиком, а отдавая найденые фрагменты обработчикам событий. Памяти практически не потребляют. Для C я один такой знаю: [yajl](https://github.com/lloyd/yajl). Если вам нужно сложить этот JSON в базу, или просто разбить на фрагменты поменьше, то больше ничего и не надо.  Наверняка и для PHP есть что-то подобное (другой вопрос - зачем именно на PHP, вам же фактически для одноразовой работы, так не всё равно на чём?)

---

P.S. Нашёлся биндинг yajl для PHP: [yajl-php](https://github.com/neikos/yajl-php)

Comment: В принципе всёравно, но я C/C++ последний раз использовал на третьем курсе универа )) не помню как с ним работать, а вот c PHP сталкиваюсь постоянно.

Comment: Для того, чтобы набрать `configure / make / make install` C знать не обязательно :) Впрочем, для PHP-шного биндинга это тоже придётся сделать.

Comment: О! Класс! спасибо! Буду пробовать!

Comment: Я правильно понял что мне сначало нужно yajl поставить весь а потом расширение для php (в INSTALL yajl-php написано требование yajl library version >= 2.0.5 available from git://github.com/lloyd/yajl)?

Comment: Ну да. Расширение для PHP просто использует эту библиотеку, а не является чисто пхп-шным портом.